# Cannot scroll content in WebView 4.4.2

Tags: android, scroll, webview

While testing my web app in Android 4.4.2's WebView, scrolling does not work on any of the elements. The javascript "onscroll" event is not being called.

However, from Android 5 and up it works fine.

EDIT: My elements that don't scroll have percent based heights (i.e. "height: 100%"), but when I change to pixel based (i.e. "height: 50px"), scrolling works. So it must have something to do with how WebView 4.4.2 renders the divs.

Comment: Is your webview inside a scroll view element?

Comment: No, just a RelativeLayout.

Comment: do you need scroll events?

Comment: In the script I do, but in Android I do not, I just want the scroll to work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to the scroll problem would be to put your webview into a scroll view. This way the webview is as big as it's content and the scroll is done by the scroll view. But the scroll events will not fire in your javascript, you need to make your scroll view observable and send these events through javascript interface. Maybe someone will provide you with a better one.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public interface OnObservableScrollViewScrolled {
        public void onObservableScrollViewScrolled(ObservableScrollView sv, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

    private OnObservableScrollViewScrolled listener;

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, -1);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style) {
        super(context, attrs, style);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        // Notify external listener
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onObservableScrollViewScrolled(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    public void setScrollListener(OnObservableScrollViewScrolled callback) {
        this.listener = callback;
    }
}
```